# JQuery Drop Down issue

Tags: jquery

> **Script for Drop Down and click event **
>
> ```
>         OUTPUT : I Randomly select multiple time with different values When I view the console I do get multiple on change events and
> ```
>
> they all are execute. I need to obtain the recent drop down value to
>   be executed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dr4').change(function () {

            console.log("change");
            var name1q=$(this).val();

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
            console.log("Click");
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) 

            {
                var data1 = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                   url: "catup123_1.php",
                    data: {"ajay": data1,"ajay12":name1q},
                   success: function (html) {
                      $("#load2222").html(html);
                 }
              });
            }
        });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ` $('input[type="checkbox"]').click` inside `$('#dr4').change` means that as many time you make the change in dropdown selection those many times `.click` event listener will get attached to those checkboxes. move that outside of `.change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can directly get the selected value from dropdown i providing you a sample of your code please check it may it help you to solve your issue**

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dr4').change(function () {
                console.log("change");
                var name1q=$(this).val();
            }); 
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
                console.log("Click");
                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    var name1q=$('#dr4').val();
                    //alert(name1q)
                    var data1 = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                       url: "catup123_1.php",
                        data: {"ajay": data1,"ajay12":name1q},
                       success: function (html) {
                          $("#load2222").html(html);
                     }
                  });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
    <select id="dr4">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">checkbox
```

Comment: Thanks ajay its my pleasure

Comment: Hi Niraj can you please help me out with one more question